# Error building Hadoop 2.0.5 - groovy/lang/GroovyObject not found

Tags: linux, hadoop

While trying to build Hadoop 2.0.5 I got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo.jspc:jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile (hdfs) on
>   project hadoop-hdfs: Execution hdfs of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo.jspc:jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile failed:
>   Unable to load the mojo 'compile' in the plugin
>   'org.codehaus.mojo.jspc:jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3'. **A required
>   class is missing: groovy/lang/GroovyObject**

This happened after running:

```
mvn package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar
```

I installed Groovy and put it in my `PATH` variable, didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

The repository files located in ~/.m2/repository were curropted

I deleted all of them and when trying to rebuild it automatically downloaded the required, uncurropted files